# How can I create a type from a schema that describes it?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For my own learning I'm trying to create something like an ODM, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to create type definitions from a schema describing a type of document. For some reason type checking for `instance` isn't working and suggestions don't work (`instance` seems to act as if it's `any` so the editor doesn't know what properties it has). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
type PropertyType = 'string' | 'number';

interface RequiredProperty<T> {
    default: T;
    optional?: false;
}

interface OptionalProperty<T> {
    default?: T;
    optional: true;
}

type BaseProperty<TKind extends PropertyType, TType> = (
    | RequiredProperty<TType>
    | OptionalProperty<TType>
) & {
    kind: TKind;
};

type StringType = BaseProperty<'string', string>;
type NumberType = BaseProperty<'number', number>;

type ModelProperty = StringType | NumberType;

interface Model {
    [x: string]: ModelProperty;
}

type ModelInstance<T extends Model> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]['kind'] extends 'string' ? string : number;
};

const model: Model = {
    str: {
        kind: 'string',
        default: 'abc'
    },
    num: {
        kind: 'number',
        optional: true
    }
};

const instance: ModelInstance<typeof model> = {
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    str: 'test',
    num: 123
}
```

I'd want `ModelInstance<typeof model>` to be something like:

```
interface Expected {
    str: string;
    num?: number;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from `ModelInstance<typeof model>`? What type it should return? Could you please provide more context? some expected result

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sorry about that, I added the type I was aiming to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to handle it.

**First one**

```js
/**
 * Please refer to this link for explanation
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
 */
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type PropertyType = 'string' | 'number';


interface RequiredProperty<T> {
  default: T;
  optional?: false;
}

interface OptionalProperty<T> {
  default?: T;
  optional: true;
}

type BaseProperty<Kind extends PropertyType, Type> = (
  | RequiredProperty<Type>
  | OptionalProperty<Type>
) & {
  kind: Kind;
};

type StringType = BaseProperty<'string', string>;
type NumberType = BaseProperty<'number', number>;

type ModelProperty = StringType | NumberType;

interface Model {
  [x: string]: ModelProperty;
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

/**
 * Translates string type name to actual type
 * Logic is pretty straitforward
 * - if ['kind'] is 'string' -> string
 * - if ['kind'] is 'number' -> number
 */
type TranslateType<T extends { kind: PropertyType }> =
  T['kind'] extends 'string'
  ? string
  : T['kind'] extends 'number'
  ? number
  : never;


type GenerateData<T extends Model> =
  /**
   * Iterate throus model data structure
   */
  {
    /**
     * If ['optional'] exists and it is true
     * Clone same data structure {kind:string, default:string}
     * into nested property, make it partial and translate 'string' to string
     */
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { optional: true } ? {
      -readonly [P in K]?: TranslateType<T[K]>
    } : {
      /**
       * Do same as above but without making data optional
       */
      -readonly [P in K]: TranslateType<T[K]>
    }
  };

/**
 * UnionToIntersection -> converts union to UnionToIntersection
 * Values -> obtain all nested properties as a union
 */
type ModelInstance<T extends Model> =
  UnionToIntersection<Values<GenerateData<T>>>

const model = {
  str: {
    kind: 'string',
    default: 'abc'
  },
  num: {
    kind: 'number',
    optional: true
  }
} as const;

type Result = ModelInstance<typeof model>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAegVGwARlAKAbApgQwM5KgJyQMyVlAC4D2xAFgJZpQKUB2A1lLiYUgB4AOCK9KRSiXrRY5IkS5oAXCBBoiKAMaMSANwK4EJAO4A6JSQC2IFCACsABgDMAdnMAmABwA2USGBEAnl0wBVeiF6ABUSAEl6IgIMJUFhAB4-AD4oAF4oAAo-KE4o%20gATGj4vKAB%20TMZpKD8ASjSUtRJKfKgq%20iQNLDrcpAKaDOgoSqgGfEIw4DrUhqb8wfKJqFaods6AbmBPH0w4LBJfLG9g7bSoAHIFLAYAczOoAB9z%20gBXIwAjAjONzYYorFxlJgAEpIACOz0oOHyu32BG88WCKQA3oN8ngUM8EEQqsENkt9nF%20AhSlUAQgMBsAL4-SKaQFQADyXEJKAQMIO8MRUBRSzRAMxRBJUFxgwJQVZVSIWGeSCpm28vigACF0Eh2XCvPEANIMFo9PrwPYcrzHXwAGmF2xS6QGS0eIPBkKQ0KNGoRVsGjyZLLZrsOmtNSCSkygADJuYNGLqqjqClTvgrMABlKU3QOnFUYdX%20%20IXVP0W4Wy43JIbRNQAByrw%20WHT6Uzar98LOL3enwtrZrpflJwAsiQ0b7Yf7TimrgX048q23a9tvr86UpMP3BxGlgBtDhVYsFgC6VRXSCHxrlW0VADVWTK0AjrcL14wkF4SLhhbvNuBIDBhVg%20GheFENA7tcxAnPwRiYKQUDKEQzysqBviiFAAAyJDXJQSgjDQXA4BIJSXCglBEKwWA6CgWBzN%20AC0IyvuuZxRgUZy7lh5zAXcVEpMBSE0ZQdEMbqzGsS21afFAnErKJWDuGemDBL%209D-gISCBgiOQcHkhTckM0aGsORwnJS1qDME9GMfkQn6lpebjrc8xQNxSw4mZgksVZNAiTOZz2Z2BCDG0HQEN8slQAA4r0BDKQAIgIKBqe5UCHggxlLJ%20gzfmEfzKRQezPDQRgDkeUD5LFDlSs8sTPDg6VgB4Sw8ksUBpY1SywGE-FisIrKWRw1BEEUBQjEQrHlUg6WtVAADC2jtA5KAQcVpWXBVsE4Ny5nSMBFp8hiWKbfm1zUi136-GQ7QKM6UA4fpXgWkYKCPkNV3kYI8F8C0Up-gBmA2TcdxQY5LW1eN65aiM9BDE%20L5vs5WpuRpvRaUiUCdUSkrSpglJlGux1UTgKD5MICAlOucDg1AcNCvJX3Kapplw8GLVY1UDUtc1x3flFZBoPNmDoNBbzqJgbzPMNOhEeQJCi1A92MSBJWKCjzLigg42NcDHN46ghP0MTUCk%20TcM4gpSlRHToO7ozjVHVAlLfM1sABEEoQRH8MSEuJKSGPQnT9VAzyBMIxBkE7wgu7SWDu0ESGXgg16eyjbyKAw0EIAgKxIBdLTXRylCZ9BRT%204HIgwB45ZJRECh8Eu8UIwaSUpdUxfh27SCxEE8Sx9e8The0v5RDFii3kkwbAN7Cgy4V6fpA1lws%20NG1sQdZxmuNO0ClUZwoG8SjeUslKr0srbzy1i%20eTWK-jajErEBjgzUlj-Pj0QCYnCCaACqcFeKYo9A14m0MCqDiSEAA)

**Second**

```js
interface OptionRequired {
  type: 'string' | 'number'
  optional: boolean
}
interface OptionPartial {
  type: 'string' | 'number'
}

type Option = OptionPartial | OptionRequired

/**
 * Translates string type name to actual type
 * Logic is pretty straitforward
 */
type TranslateType<T extends Option> =
  T['type'] extends 'string'
  ? string
  : T['type'] extends 'number'
  ? number
  : never;

/**
 * Check if optional exists
 * if false - apply never, because union of T|never produces t
 * if true - apply undefined
 */
type ModifierType<T extends Option> =
  T extends { optional: true }
  ? undefined
  : never

/**
 * Apply TranslateType 'string' -> string
 * Apply ModifierType {optional:true} -> undefined
 */
type TypeMapping<T extends Option> = TranslateType<T> | ModifierType<T>

/**
 * Apply all conditions to each option
 */
type Mapping<T> = T extends Record<string, Option> ? {
  -readonly [Prop in keyof T]: TypeMapping<T[Prop]>
} : never

type Data<Options> = Mapping<Options>

const model = {
  a: {
    type: 'string',
    optional: true,
  },
  b: {
    type: 'number',
    optional: false
  },
  c: {
    type: 'string',
  },
} as const

type Result = Data<typeof model>

declare var x:Result

type a = typeof x.a // string | undefined
type b = typeof x.b // number
type c = typeof x.c // string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgEoQCOArsFBACbIDeAUMsmAJ7oQBcyA5AM5hSgBzTsgA%20XEMQC2AI2id6ybJhwg4AGw7Ts2NRDghaAX1qhIsRCgxZcABThQs6mguasOPPoOFjOEmXKNaWldLZVxkAF40MJA7B2AnMSsVAhIySiCAegAqbPps5AAVKH1uNThIbmRefhABRhYUVUkUMGxkRDBiJxD85AAZbAFgBGRgKvRyMGZqvjhgMBhsKAB3ewp8zODGopKQMoqIQsaAHkLkCAAPSBAKKuTcAD5IhUKAbU4QzgBdC%20uIW5VDy1IQKAD8sxBCg470%20jR%20fxud3EUlkUHkDAhfjR0OQIAgADdoABuLK5PoAYQAFhAEABrMYwRQxJxXcZgbh9YBM%20BqbgoAC0HXQ6DUTDxhOgABpkLIEHBiPzkMQQCpFEzCiJ8USoMhJtgKMQkFUwFymXxiILhaLxSqKBAYKAMshslsQsgALIG7nAaDHVhnREA5EPEDPCKvIOAmjM6yqDSMKCW5DGTHK24Op0bBgcbXQMl5F3IACCIrFu1K5Ug-pQwK8yAFzxqgj6pZtnu9jr9O2oSjj6jYFoghgbzztmfx2dd21YRUaHrgIsEgauSPuMXDFf2VaOp0KzzEXooPu7Af3BdbZfF6jUyAQuGPcZN7T0CCpsZUmxnKAXS7qZ03c5V2DKoCHvKAKBOZs6hlUNnghOgGAFcg4AoXByzeGwoCUMYQGQOkICYbANW%20GF50XdBl3eLClG%20R4jGQXNJSgIJ3QAEQqOATlDbhN1-Sj-x4%20jaHvfYwGQSQDQgW8okQjoODkhgQncaChClBQGD7FQB0TS11IYQx9NlBSNIaNwUX8dEjM0lkE15fkFEMhQEBMhglMaFTPDqTgjKckc4CqUTeFYnYCG4Yg1HEqIOLALiQmIiSpLUYT7QQcpyGQAl7GQS42DCiLTW-DpIjMiAEsuAA6OBkEyTJIUEUR03tR1JyK6QSviplKva2q8VRfN3VGKJOpyirRl61SgA)

Personaly, I think that it is better to use `required` property instead of `optional` and accordingly reverse the boolean flags.

I mean to use `{required:true}` instead of `{optional: false}`.

It is more readable, but again, it is only my opinion.

Please take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669744/infer-types-using-own-properties/68670399#68670399). This case is VERY similar to yours

Comment: @user11628429 no problem. If it was useful, please don't forget to upvote the answer