# How to infer types of an object created from a schema?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement something similar to [storybook's "Controls" feature](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#dealing-with-complex-values) where you can define a bunch of properties, and they become controls in the UI.

I defined a schema type and a schema of how to create those controls:

```
// Example schema
var newSchema: BlockSchema = {
  title: "New Schema",
  controls: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      placeholder: 'Please insert your name'
    },
    size: {
      type: 'select',
      options: ['quarter', 'half', 'full']
    },
    hasInfo: {
      type: 'bool'
    },
    amount: {
      type: 'number'
    }
  }
}
```

But now I need a type that is the result of what the user has selected. A type for the final values, something like:

```
type MapControlTypes = {
  bool: boolean;
  string: string;
  select: string;
  number: number;
};

type InferType<T extends BlockSchema> = { /* MapControlTypes<?????????> */ }

type NewSchemaControls = InferType<typeof newSchema>;

/* Expected result:
  NewSchemaControls = {
    name: string;
    size: string;
    hasInfo: boolean;
    amount: number;
  }
*/
```

**I need to infer the types from the `controls` property of my schema, but how could I implement this inference?** [Here's a playground with complete example code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmAwgewHbAE7IDYBVwQDOUAvFAN4BQUUARsjgFx0PYRyoDc1UhmAlqgDmzPhkFDuNQhDYBjYKIHCpUVAFcAtrQgZmG7bu4BfbpVCQoAIVbtUKdFmykKPCxGYByejk8mz7lAAyspCDpg4LlQ07l5iEn48YNhwchAAFjgAJroA-EriKpSmlOYEwbIQCuFOUW4EcZUKiTTIYMD8aIQFEgDaALr+pYEAclo6GDWRZNFQsVCeBhOJJWWWU85kNjh2G1AAPsGhe4dBTcAnUGOGk2gR2GYQAB5gyBjAc+UbQXLpEJpwfCQYhkDa9TzuTyDUrPV7vT7rO5OH5-AF1GgAegAVFieFAsVAAIJQORIyL8YioOCaCBZOggKD8YDEADWEBAeKxGJ4vTZIB6wn6zA2Q0osLeH0CVmwyDkLJR-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)

---

I tried implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676771/how-can-i-create-a-type-from-a-schema-that-describes-it/), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669744/infer-types-using-own-properties?noredirect=1&lq=1) solution. [But they don't work well](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmAwgewHbAE7IDYBVwQDOUAvFAN4BQUUA9LbAscABbQBuc2ArtAJaooAIlCQhAGijBkUAO4s4wKWygQAHpADGwCABMpBZYqgBrCCCiEWybtn0L2EalABGyHAC5X77BDioAbmdCTAEAcy8QjHCgmkIIX21I0NQw2KhUbgBbFwgML0ycvKCAXyDKUWgAIR8-VBR0LGxSCmdKrwByNxwO0vLKqABlFLCGzBwWqhp2qA6o8N7nMGw4TQhrOzyAfmTo1L7KCsNBhIhtMabJtoJO+MTgRZpkMGA+NEJd8IBtAF0Do8gUAActlchgLhMyFMDJBOoUwYsyocBhDmmQajg6qioAAfIYjbF4k73QnA0F5VHldRgZAYJQotDjbCDTRsLJwfCQYhkVFfDqVDp-Q7U2n0wyollsuBXGi0ABUcucUDlUAAglBNIzLnxiKg4Fk9K4LHxgMQzCAlXLaM4vubPqkfl5KZQkZQRXSYdVsMhNCZJRB2TKpCbfPa0s56FAAHQxqAAeVYeUswG4ADNU4dZQrLVAACIQVMCIhyBRKTWNHDEKw2OyuaDV2SoS3WmjlpkfKAS1kBuD-eWK5VQADEI9HY-H1BVmgQwDgAgAtCBkIRCHBov45pYcNxXmhJ8Px4fR5PrZR+-vcBh-IQVjoqyNPRl9dBpFBVimuJ79wAZZBhPiaFAOpQGAGAQMAoDJleJqprSshrroJ4AtAl7XreECchAAA8uCqGoOioLoxCogAfKQzi4HyAo-HhBFEbM8ypB0zhbFB4TOF4lH8gQgq0RAhHEF0PjMTQrHdL4-gcRkECOBg5TnoOiBsL6QGplAug9oRhrqDqpr7nwamYLwUDzm+YDLBYqAyXkki5NO3DxFA3CoG8gjIGpuA4lZskgVgujcGsxC4PpamplwjmmQgFlOVphZWYhyrWgMMDILoBl8HkmE4XxAmdlqOBkSQFE5fR5DqZpGm6F44l1FAJQsVAXEaeyWm6Lx6h0cwGC8A13l5FJTUVXo7X4fx9Fhdg8QNc5GlxXoUl9RgUkzQWRaIWe2aDqq5nYBYqGoDeigYYYcwjB0JlkYxYT7tt0UpWlhaZYY5DNf4lUeBNEAlBdMWzWtUC0tJslIQMmHwOZ4TZR1Y3Efl2CFY1V4HehWW4GReL3elT2QDhJGHApKq3btb7YM05ZpbuB1SDIfisgDLyuSDhjg2AkNoy0uHQ7lABKZy0roWFXZIpFQKx0JfAAClgYBAYI5ruY1jqNQQLNs5L0s-Hj30FNZS1ngwACiaj6ss9bduylCcBg0myP67JeFU3q+nb0pQm0IYQF4QhAhAshDObcASM4bZNB20I0HqBpeOHNCercZ3iEqsfLKs6w4Bp+SzBLEmOQI8Qeku3DW5HEAibHJSJ7Hlh8AAXp7rRV9MNwMac2gdJXjfPJTHZ8gAjtwa46Bg7ezAo2CpiPHSprY2CCknFdJwohAAJKoLB0dJ03sKzOJZc0AvVf6jY6Ab43cezPCeR73Vzj1fVyFQKvqbY9hnOjbljs+n6AcI6rqQ4XyEOlZBQkX6IYH2tsA6om5I-NeL8sKVAVlZSBUpQH4xVEbLQOh9BgUILYYAHhriAggS7aBQYI7PjDOkOItd65XWoVAJeT9kDVVqP4BhR9nIEIyOSOSt9MydiLmBdAUBcH4MIVvaAJCoFwxgTHL4agwxKxWnNXQ6R6pWkoEAA) and also only support two types.

<strike>[Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71785520/4615459) didn't work too. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmAwgewHbAE7IDYBVwQDOUAvFAN4BQUUARsjgFx0PYRyoDc1UhmAlqgDmzPhkFDuNQhDYBjYKIHCpUVAFcAtrQgZmG7bu4BfbpVCQoAIVbtUKdFmykKPCxGYByejk8mz7lAAyspCDpg4LlQ07l5iEn48YNhwchAAFjgAJroA-EriKpSmlOYEwbIQCuFOUW4EcZUKiTTIYMD8aIQFEgDaALr%20pYEAclo6GDWRZNFQsVCeBhOJJWWWU85kNjh2G1AAPsGhe4dBTcAnUGOGk2gR2GYQAB5gyBjAc%20UbQXLpEJpwfCQYhkDa9TzuTyDUrPV7vT7rO5OH5-AF1GgAegAVFieFAsVAAIJQORIyL8YioOCaCBZOggKD8YDEADWEBAeKxGJ4vTZIB6wn6zA2Q0osLeH0CVmwyDkLJR-zg6LmTLYAskPAxGKgADo9VAAPLAP4YXjAdQAMwtpUxOM5UAAIhALYIiFAAO7pOAfUmOHDEQiZdTYOk6XiZd2oTncmi%20%207dKDfX6K0VaqAAUSe1OS0EIyYBlAAbnBTagIO6FQDmNLZfL80qZm5VR4oAAiEbl4L11sAGh4cacCdmNCpNOYw5oCJbnniwk8fcnk%20SqQy2V0XgACmw4DJGagZPCQMh1KXqRBPHioMYF5PCPwAF4ticxBoLGTyYDzy%20tdqdffMcEAEd1BLYBdHnBYvWwC0IM8C1g2wKFL2vS8vUIABJVALWQcdvynLwfEQ5Cbxoalj3QXDFxfSAvCWcDkJ4YximGcpMItXQgQgAAeXAoGeMDUCyYgazlSs4AAPmVABaDB2CyNBsAZXoNz3KA%20WQC0oFwcEB39KEhVgBANk4whem0zxdOwQgoWU-pwUhfp%20mYtZoA7Ct6w2EEoDYjiCC49wNLUcsxPEsxsQzF4qjAulZMIYNFHqSw3LEzzlRHM91VUaQHxbWcNUXNC2Jwlgdg4LKoDI9QKLUcYjEYyguUoIA), but it has a very similar problem that happened when I tried other solutions. Maybe is it because I'm not using MapControlTypes on my ControlSchema?</strike>

---

[Solved!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmAwgewHbAE7IDYBVwQDOUAvFAN4BQUUARsjgFx0PYRyoDc1UhmAlqgDmzPhkFDuNQhDYBjYKIHCpUVAFcAtrQgZmG7bu4BfbpVCQoAIVbtUKdFmykKPCxGYByejk8mz7lAAyspCDpg4LlQ07l5iEn48YNhwchAAFjgAJroA-EriKpSmlOYEwbIQCuFOUW4EcZUKiTTIYMD8aIQFEgDaALr%20pYEAclo6GDWRZNFQsVCeBhOJJWWWU85kNjh2G1AAPsGhe4dBTcAnUGOGk2gR2GYQAB5gyBjAc%20UbQXLpEJpwfCQYhkDa9TzuTyDUrPV7vT7rO5OH5-AF1GgAegAVFieFAsVAAIJQORIyL8YioOCaCBZOggKD8YDEADWEBAeKxGJ4vTZIB6wn6zA2Q0osLeH0CVmwyDkLJR-zg6LmTLYAskPAxGKgADo9VAAPLAP4YXjAdQAMwtpUxOM5UAAIhALYIiFAAO7pOAfUmOHDEQiZdTYOk6XiZd2oTncmi%20%207dKDfX6K0W%20vh0dT8EPS2Xy5NosgAHisUGewAgqCyxBzcoVAIAfAAKWjMKwASlI9bopS1UAAok9qcloIR83BKAA3OCm1AQd11pVkWiZ7My2tjxuzDrANVQABEIznwTHe4ANDw404E7MaFSacwbzQER4FvFhJ5z0%20n8lUhlsrovAABTYOAZEZVAZHhEBkHUGdqQgTw8SgYxPyfQh%20AALxfR8YgaV9QkQr8UKQr1CAASVQC1kAfJDcMgLwfGwQin2Ir9qRg9AaK-OiX0WcZdGYmhjB4YTjDbAJygoi1dCBCBC1wUsnnLStqzXPNUTgLsZh4ABaDB2CyNBsAZXpAPAqA%20WQC0oFwcFL39KEhVgBANlkwhelszx7OwQgoVM-pwUhfp%20mKYZykPecxw2EEoCkmSCELdwrLUOcF3rMxsX7F4qnLOl9MIYNFHqSwIoXaLlVveD1VUaRMJfN8NS-UipOolgdg4GqoHY9ROLUfiMFUYSuUoIA)

Comment: You mean you want the schema and document to become dynamic ?

Comment: No, the schema types are the same, but the user may create dynamic documents. I fixed the playground urls, which should help understand the problem a bit better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, using a mapped type, but first you need to preserve the original type of the schema. If you add a type annotation to it, then information about specific fields and types will be lost. It will just be a `BlockSchema`

The easiest way to do this is to omit the annotation, and use an `as const` assertion to make the compiler infer literal types for `type`.

With this extra info in hand, we can then use  a mapped type to transform  the schema into an object type:

```
type InferType<T extends BlockSchema> = {
  -readonly [P in keyof T['controls']]: MapControlTypes[T['controls'][P]['type']]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgNgewMYGsDKSAWEC2BDKAXigG8AoKKJBAO2ACcE4BnALigCUI8ATWuEAB4u1ej0HMGASxoBzADSkKlKPW58aAqKEjsUEEAgBmUALJ4wAYVoMmAFXARmygL4A+N2RdkyAel9QAKIAHng4YHDQzFi4eGQAbnj0UDQQAO4Y2PhESpTAUsCR7ABEAHLpUJmxxfLK1HSMLOzkKilhEM3KrTodUADkkvQysn21rZQReEgQmEw8EPTsfQAKkXjM0DIb9MBQhgCuyTTtfV1QLmMqzFIAXr0t4z1LG5FIwKNnlAhg+bRsUABtPoAR32SWAC1G-UweDgRihfSM+zgcD6AF0zhczjDmABJGhGBCdcbaRxLABGCCYp1aWNaYQQ+zoxMeZP6NH2OHJkMxri8UHWVD+wB8ZB6Zgs1ga9kczByD0pTHYirWNAA3MpBsN2Fq5BrKC8IG8ddI9coOVyFuwLdz6BqXBqxY4oPijAsHJBBHYoBBghCaDw5fBkOgYvg3PLlABaNS8fggQHLKAyKD6QwmOxA+q2FjotHscxWGyND1OAGZvrZxrMdEA5ZooE9PNeHzi8oZMN4KU5uXEV3uxyCHrGFLpKrhx2+ABUQWCkDeEB4qicyOArGU7fHXeLTF7uRUxxwvV1sn1V1ux9Np+x61dRKgKu46rODKZa5SnNtZ+8U98QA)

You can also use a function to create the schema, and be more selective about what gets the readonly treatment:

```
function buildBlockSchema<B extends BlockSchema>(b: B) {
  return b
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgNgewMYGsDKSAWEC2BDKAXigG8AoKKJBAO2ACcE4BnALigCUI8ATWuEAB4u1ej0HMGASxoBzADSkKlKPW58aAqKEjsUEEAgBmUALJ4wAYVoMmAFXARmygL4A+N2RdkyRgK40SMBStFAARn5ScDzwyOhYuHiCMFAQAB7AEDQ8zLCIqBjY+G4AFGHsMACUSpRqwH70NOFePgD0rVAAoml4OGBw0MwJ+GQAbnj0UDQQAO6FiUThkdGxBcN4JeSUwcAD7ABEAHKzUPP4+-LK1HSMLOxbKjS9EPfKKtqO7ADkkvQysl9Lu9KP08EgIJgmDwIPRvgAFAZ4ZjQGTI+jAKCGBpTZ5fN5QFxAlTMKQALxeNWBOgpPwgAyCgPxlAQYGCtDYUAA2l8AI5+CaZeiAqBfTB4OBGYVffxwOBfAC6+MJ+LFzAAkjQjAhXsCProRWEEEw8e9le9eggAsAdVTPiKaH4cGEYSaVN5KN4XJUfGRqWYLNYbvZHLliA9DUx2BHETQANzKX7-diJuTxyjI+nWqAp2RpqaO52w-NOmHxlzx32OKAaowwhyQQR2VIZLI5PJxM54NyLB4AWjUvH4IC5cKgMig+kMJjs3OuthYCvl7HMVhst3rTk5M6+c9uzAVnLh8u51MXLUrkCgxzm60D89D1c1dccgmpxims07bgrrQAVF00kgIIIB4VQnD8OBrWUa9OzvPce3xJ4cApHM83TMkUOkVMVSRGttXCI0YzQqALStdgHRLeg828X9WiAA)

Comment: It didn't fully work(edited the post with the playground url), unfortunately. But curiously, it has a very similar problem that happened when I tried other solutions. Maybe is it because I'm not using `MapControlTypes` on my `ControlSchema`?

I saw that the complete example playground link was broken, and fixed those too. If it helps.

Comment: Oh wait. No I understand what you mean by removing type anotation and using const. Let me try something. Will keep you posted

Comment: No success. I actually need `BlockSchema` because it helps defining what type exists when writing the schema itself, and what fields are available for a type. (string type has placeholder, where select has options). And If we remove the annotation. We lose the autocomplete in there. So maybe what I want is not possible?

Comment: Solved by using the function approach!

Comment: @assisrMatheus Sorry, was offline. glad it worked out